# Explicit Solution of Quadratic Opt. Problem

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming

I have the following optimization problem I am unsure whether I've got it correct:

$$
\text{min } x^Tx \\
\text{so that } a + c^Tx <= 0
$$

I have introduced a slack variable $s$ to make it conceptually (for me) simpler:

$$
\text{min } x^Tx \\
\text{so that } a + c^Tx - s^2 = 0
$$

wich leades to the langragian $L = x^Tx + \lambda(a + c^Tx - s^2)$, from which I follow $2x = - \lambda c$ and from $a + c^Tx - s^2 = 0 \iff a + \lambda c^Tc - s^2 = 0$ that if $a >= 0$ then $\lambda = 0$ else $\lambda = -\frac{a}{<c,c>}$ (since we want to minimize $x^Tx = \lambda^2(c^Tc)$).

Comment: If $a \le 0$, then $x^\ast = 0$. If $a > 0$, we have $c^T x \le -a < 0$ which results in $(c^Tx)^2 \ge a^2$. Using C-S, we have $(c^Tc)(x^Tx) \ge (c^Tx)^2$. Thus, we have $x^Tx \ge \frac{a^2}{c^Tc}$. Then, we obtain $x^\ast = -a \frac{c}{c^Tc}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stationary conditions are

$$
\cases{
2x+\lambda c=0\\
a+c'x+s^2=0\\
\lambda s = 0
}
$$

now developing, and considering the case $s=0$ we follow with

$$
\cases{
2x+\lambda c=0\\
a+c'x=0
}\ \ \Rightarrow 2c'x+\lambda c'c=0\Rightarrow x = -\frac{a}{c'c}c
$$

and calculating $\|x\|^2=\frac{a^2}{c'c}$. Now considering $\lambda=0$ we can calculate also the corresponding stationary point etc.

Comment: ah of course, i mixed plus and minus! The mistake is obvious in hindsight